# using a different conda-build root directory

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am creating my own conda recipe which I checkout with git. The repository is few gigs. Instead of doing a checkout in `~/conda-bld`, I would like it to checkout in `/ssd`, which is going to be faster. How can I specify it?
Also, how can I specify git depth when doing a clone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like it to checkout in `/ssd` which is going to be faster. How can I specify it?

`conda-build` chooses a root directory for all of its work in the following way:

1. If `CONDA_BLD_PATH` is defined in your environment, use that
2. Otherwise, if a file named `~/.condarc` exists, check if `conda-build/root-dir` is defined.  For example:

```
   # .condarc
   conda-build:
     root-dir: /ssd/conda-bld
```

3. Otherwise, try `$(conda info --root)/conda-bld`
4. If that location isn't writable, use `~/conda-bld`

(See the [source code](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/blob/555b93350887bb6975b43a0fd7d9fcd27eb0ea0a/conda_build/config.py#L98-L111) for these steps if you're curious.)

> Also, how can I specify git depth when doing a clone?

You can use `git_depth` in the `source` section of `meta.yaml`:

```
# meta.yaml
package:
  name: foo
  version: '1.0'

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/foo/bar
  git_depth: 1
```

Note: I do not recommend using `git_depth`. It won't work well if you also specify a `git_tag` -- If the tag is not visible within N commits (for `git_depth: N`) of the `HEAD`, then your checkout will fail.

Comment: git_depth doesn't seem to be a valid argument. Error: in section u'source': unknown key u'git_depth'

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that error.  I tried conda-build 1.21.6 and (py2) conda-build 2.0.0 (py2 and py3).  What version of conda-build are you using?  (`conda build --version`)