# How to install my own python module (package) via conda and watch its changes

Tags: python, module, package, anaconda, miniconda

I have a file `mysql.py`, which I use in almost all of my projects. Since I do not want to copy and paste the same file into each of these projects I wrote a module - possibly a package in the future.

## Question

How do I add a local module to my conda environment, and automatically update or watch it when I change something in `mysql.py`? How to do the same for a package?

I would like to avoid to set up a local channel/repository and just reference to the folder with `mysql.py`.

Comment: did you try `conda develop` or `pip -e`?

Answer (score 58):

If you install the conda build package (and you have a package, not just a script), you can install in "editable" mode:

```
conda develop .
```

(running from the directory with your script). This is very similar to the "editable" mode from pip

```
pip install -e .
```

Either approach lets you uninstall packages with either

```
conda develop -u .
```

or

```
pip uninstall .
```

If you just have a script (not a package), you can edit or set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the directory with the script.

Comment: how do you know when to you `pip -e` vs `conda develop`?

Comment: If you're using conda, you should use `conda develop`. The only small problem I ran into with `conda develop` was that it would not install `console_scripts`, whereas `pip install -e` would. This may have been fixed in conda in the meantime though.

Comment: how do you check if things were installed? I tried running `conda list` but nothing familiar to my project/packages seem to show up.

Comment: It should show up in the output of `conda list`. Do you have a `setup.py` file properly configured? Does `pip install -e` work?

Comment: @CharlieParker See https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/ for pip vs conda.

Comment: After installing conda build, using the conda develop option worked but the package does not show up in conda list. It shows up in pip list and imports fine. I know conda list shows somewhat different items than pip list, but I would expect it to show my package like pip list does. Anyone know why it doesn't? When installed with pip install -e . the package shows up in both pip list and conda list

Comment: See [http://evantilton.com/guides/anacondapythonpath/](http://evantilton.com/guides/anacondapythonpath/) for a simple method to programmatically change `PYTHONPATH` for a particular conda environment.

Comment: Note that `conda develop` is not actively maintained and there is a request to deprecate or remove it, see https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4251. So **it is not advisable to use `conda develop` in 2021.

Comment: Adding to @MartinHepp: The recommendation seems to remain: use `python setup.py develop` or `pip install -e ` instead, see https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1992.

Comment: @JustinP. that isse at conda is basically a bunch of developers who are super confused about what to do: it seems conda should provide a canonical source of guidance about this. In the meantime, I will try using `pip install -e .` until it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, conda develop doens't "install" the local module, like by running hte setup, like pip does, is just adds it to the path.

Answer (score 48):

While the previous answers are doing what I need, I just want to show what I will be using instead. Since it was my plan to learn about conda packages anyway...

#### 0. Good sources

1. [Michael Sarahan - Making packages and packaging "just work" | YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kamld5Z-xx0)
2. [GitHub - audreyr/cookiecutter: A command-line utility that creates projects from cookiecutters (project templates)](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter)
   and use one of these templates:

   - [GitHub - audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage: Cookiecutter template for a Python package.](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage)
   - [GitHub - conda/cookiecutter-conda-python: A cookiecutter template for conda packages using Python](https://github.com/conda/cookiecutter-conda-python) (This is what I used)

#### 1. Create a python package template for conda using cookiecutter

```
conda install -c conda-forge cookiecutter
```

Now change to the directory where you want to initialize your package, then do:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/conda/cookiecutter-conda-python.git
```

This will ask for some basic information about the package that you want to create. Then change into your repo

```
cd myrepo
```

#### 2. Build your package

make sure `conda-build` is installed, if not run

```
conda install conda-build
```

Make sure to set the `CONDA_BLD_PATH` as mentioned in [anaconda - using a different conda-build root directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39276821/1623867). This will be the directory where you can find your packages, then run:

```
conda build conda.recipe
```

to build your package and clean up after you with

```
conda build purge
```

#### 3. Set up your own local channel (no uploading to anaconda.org)

Read

- [Creating custom channels — Conda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html)
- [python - add local channel to .condarc on windows - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42453584/1623867)

for help.

Index each platform. Maybe someone can confirm that this step is not needed, as my builds already  contain the `repodata.json`. Otherwise:

```
conda index D:\CODE\condamychannel\win-64
```

Test if the package can be found with

```
conda search -c file:///D:\CODE\condamychannel --override-channels mypackage
```

or add the channel to the config directly (per environment)

```
conda config --add channels file:///D:\CODE\condamychannel
```

#### 4. Install (and update) the package

```
activate myenv
```

and

```
conda install mypackage
```

Once I change `mypackage`, I give it a new version number in `meta.yaml` and `setup.py` and build the package with `conda build conda.recipe`.
Updating is simply

```
conda update mypackage
```

See if your package works:

```
python
>>> import cli from mypackage
>>> cli.cli()
CLI template
```

---

This may not be the optimal way, but I could not find a tutorial that contains all the steps I outlined above.

Comment: why did you choose to not use `conda develop` or `pip -e`?

Comment: Why doing it the easy way if it can be done so much more cumbersome!

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions here but it said at "cookiecutter https://github.com/conda/cookiecutter-conda-python.git" that git is not installed. I tried conda install git but I got the same message.

Comment: I actually like this approach better than `conda develop` because you can also include your own modules in environment YAML files and more. Also, upgrading to a fully-fledged public module is straightforward this way.

Comment: Addendum: Using `pip` in conda environments works, but there are lots of reports of potential issues with this. It seems to work okay for a new environment, but updating may create inconsistencies. Personally I try to avoid pip inside a conda environment.

Comment: Addendum 2: There is a request to deprecate `conda develop` from `conda`, see https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4251

Answer (score 1):

I had a wrapper function that I had to call multiple times on different scripts.So, I copied that file `wrappers.py` to the Anaconda *site-packages* folder. On my computer this was at: *C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages*. Then, whenever I needed `wrappers.py`, I'd just import it in my scripts, like this:

```
import wrappers
```

If you want to make sure that the import was successful, you could either select Anaconda as your dev environment in your IDE and then invoke the Intellisense after import: `from wrappers import (intellisense suggestions)`. Or you could also use IDLE:

```
>>> import wrappers
>>>(if you get this prompt, this means the import was successful).
```

Conda integration is only possible if you create [custom channels](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html). This is because conda searches for packages in the following locations(based on your OS) and to tell conda to search for your module at certain location(s), you must install `conda-build` to create a custom channel:

```
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

If you want to avoid creating a repo/channel, then a simple import as above should do the job. In addition, if you make any changes to your module and save it, you will always have the latest `import` in your scripts.