# Manually installing python packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have run into a problem while installing `pychopg2` into my work computer (windows btw). Using `pip` wasn't an option, due to network restrictions, so I have learned how to install packages manually, and after some attempts, it seems to be working and installation runs without error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\compat.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\errorcodes.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\errors.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\extensions.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\extras.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\pool.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\sql.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\tz.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\_ipaddress.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\_json.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\_lru_cache.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\_psycopg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\_range.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\psycopg2\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\compat.py to compat.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\errorcodes.py to errorcodes.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\errors.py to errors.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\extensions.py to extensions.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\extras.py to extras.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\pool.py to pool.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\sql.py to sql.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\tz.py to tz.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\_ipaddress.py to _ipaddress.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\_json.py to _json.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\_lru_cache.py to _lru_cache.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\_range.py to _range.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
creating stub loader for psycopg2\_psycopg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\psycopg2\_psycopg.py to _psycopg.cpython-37.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
writing build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO\native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
psycopg2.__pycache__._psycopg.cpython-37: module references __file__
creating 'dist\psycopg2-2.8.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing psycopg2-2.8.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
removing 'c:\users\user\anaconda\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.8.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\users\user\anaconda\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.8.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
Extracting psycopg2-2.8.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg to c:\users\user\anaconda\lib\site-packages
psycopg2 2.8.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\user\anaconda\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.8.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for psycopg2==2.8.4
Finished processing dependencies for psycopg2==2.8.4
```

But my code editor still complains about 'No module named psychopg2'. I am using anaconda3, added to path during installation. It seems that it could cause problems but I don't know if it is what is causing the package not to be recognized. Also, when I run `python` from cmd, it says:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

But when I go to the folder where the environment is supposed to be, it is empty. So I tried to create one, and I get another network error. I'm getting out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the Anaconda interpreter without activating the environment.

Run `conda activate env_name` where `env_name` is the environment you created or `base` for the default environment. Then, install your package from within the environment using either conda (preferred) or pip and run Python while the environment is active.

Comment: It did activate the env, but when I tried ```conda install setup.py``` it gave ```CondaHTTPError```, which seems to be network related. So I tried ```python setup.py install``` and it installed, and when I ran ```python``` it no longer gave me the "environment not activated" message, but I still coudn't import psychopg2

Comment: You didn't install it correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474575/how-to-install-my-own-python-module-package-via-conda-and-watch-its-changes