# Custom module installed but can import by name

Tags: python, conda, setup.py, distutils

I have a [project](https://github.com/liamwazherealso/myfuncondaproject/tree/deploy-docker) which I'm trying package with conda, install, and run.

I cannot import the module by name, although installed. I can however import the module `main.py` and execute it's function `print_hi`. Demonstrated below.

```
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 31 2022, 08:41:55) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myfuncondaproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfuncondaproject'
>>> import main
>>> main.print_hi("Liam")
Hi, Liam
```

My project structure.

```
myfuncondaproject/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── setup.py
```

Seems to be in line with [suggested file structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998845/1325202), although I'm assuming the problem lies in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Python looks for imports in the sys.path folders. When you check sys.path on the Python prompt, you'll always find the current folder at the first place.

I guess in your case the current folder is myfuncondaproject and this is why Python can find the *main* module. To find *myfuncondaproject* itself you would need to add its parent folder to sys.path

Note the the recommended way of installing own packages is the *editable install*. With conda this is

```
conda develop <path to  myfuncondaproject>
```

[How to install my own python module (package) via conda and watch its changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474575/how-to-install-my-own-python-module-package-via-conda-and-watch-its-changes)

Comment: I'm looking to install my package from a channel https://anaconda.org/pieri.liam/myfuncondaproject, not install locally.

Comment: Good to know. But then why can't you install it, but just the main module? Did you check sys.path?