# Structure for developmental Python packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm starting a brand new project. I'm splitting code of different functions (e.g., `utils`, `database`, `main application`) into their own respective packages such that other new projects can just add them as dependencies and import them in the future. Packages may have cross-dependencies (e.g., `database` depends on `utils`).

I know that I can build each component as a Python package and use pip to manage the dependencies. However, as I'm starting from scratch, I will be making active changes to all packages at the same time. It seems to me packaging them as a "proper package" would be quite inefficient. I envisage that I will need to add a new function in say `utils`, increment the version, use it `database`, then realise that I need another new function that belongs in `utils`, increment version again etc.

What would be the best way to structure the project in this scenario? I'm using conda, Python 3.10 and VSCode if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the package approach you are thinking about. The key method you're missing is to make editable installs locally for all your packages.

`pip install -e .` in package root directory

Editable installs will reflect their changes right away in your environment

Since you are using `conda` you probably want `conda develop .` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49478207/3936044) suggests

Comment: Thanks @Mandera. From the answer, seems like conda develop is no longer actively maintained by the Conda team. But `pip install -e .` worked.